# Unexpected Future.map() execution order

Tags: scala

I have a following Scala program:

```
object FutureMapTest extends App {
   println("start")

   val f: Future[Long] = Future {
     Thread.sleep(2000)
     val x = 1
     println(s"started with ${x}")
     x
   }
   f.map { i =>
     println(s"mapped to ${i*2}")
   }
   f.map {
     val nothing = "nothing"
     println(s"mapped to ${nothing}")
     _ * 2
   }

   Thread.sleep(3000)
   println("end")
}
```

What I'd expect it to print on the console is

```
start
started with 1
```

followed by (in any order):

```
mapped to 2
mapped to nothing
```

followed by

```
end
```

What it actually prints is:

```
start
mapped to nothing
started with 1
mapped to 2
end
```

So, it seems like the second "map" block gets executed immediately, without waiting for the original future to complete. How is that possible?

You can even remove Thread.sleep() from the original future block, the result would still be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple sources of confusion here.

This:

```
f.map {
  val nothing = "nothing"
  println(s"mapped to ${nothing}")
  _ * 2
}
```

Expands to:

```
f.map {
  val nothing = "nothing"
  println(s"mapped to ${nothing}")
  i => i * 2
}
```

What does this mean? `Future#map` expects a function argument of a `A => B` for some `Future[A]`. The expression:

```
val nothing = "nothing"
println(s"mapped to ${nothing}")
i => i * 2
```

..Evaluates to `Long => Long`, but the val assignment and `println` are evaluated *first* because they are part of the expression that returns the function. `i => i * 2` isn't executed until `f` completes. This is similar to ([Scala puzzler 001](http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-001)):

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3) map {
     |    val a = 1 // this only happens once, not three times
     |    i => a + i + 1
     | }
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5)
```

Changing it to this will exhibit the behavior you expect (now that val assignment and `println` are *part of* the function body):

```
f.map { i =>
  val nothing = "nothing"
  println(s"mapped to ${nothing}")
  i * 2
}
```

Here's another way to look at it:

```
f.map {
  println("evaluated immediately")
  i => { println("evaluated after f"); i * 2 }
}
```

Comment: The other confusion is that "end" must come last in the absence of more guarantees.